# Location of cursor image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress

i have the following code to use a "cursor trail" in wordpress. 
once inserted, the "cursor trail" is visible, however the image location cannot be found

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

            //create img elements having pointer.png in their src 
            pointer = $('<img>').attr({'src':'pointer.png'});

            //and append them to document
            $(document.body).append(pointer); 

            //show them at mouse position & fade out slowly
            pointer.css({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    top: e.pageY +2 ,    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX +2   //offsets
                }).fadeOut(1500);   
});
});
```

I have edited the path to the image cursor as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

            //create img elements having pointer.png in their src 
            pointer = $('<img>').attr({'wp-content/uploads/2012/07/':'meerkat2.gif'});

            //and append them to document
            $(document.body).append(pointer); 

            //show them at mouse position & fade out slowly
            pointer.css({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    top: e.pageY +2 ,    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX +2   //offsets
                }).fadeOut(1500);   
});
});
```

Please can someone perhaps point out why the path to the image source is incorrect?

Comment: What happens when you use an absolute path?

Comment: `wp-content/uploads/2012/07/` is not a valid html attribute, nor are you calling .attr() properly. `.attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/.../meerkat2.gif')` would be better.

Comment: @CallumMcLean - still the same problem. It shows that "missing image icon"

Comment: @MarcB thank you very much. The image now shows. The trails are "staying" on the page, how could i perhaps change it so that the "trail" dissappears after a while?

Comment: Honestly you don't need the trail, it distracts the user more than anything

Comment: @Huangism I know..unfortunately the owner of the site is insisting on the trail

Comment: well then, you can always fadeout the img and then remove it after say 5 seconds or whatever

Comment: @Huangism thank you. would this be done by editing the .fadeOut(1500);  ?

Comment: I would like it to look like the cursor trail on http://www.nkangalodge.co.za/

Comment: oh nvm I thought you wanted to get rid of the entire trail at some point. their trail looks like the image is being layered with about 5 px down right each layer and when mouse moves it's probably getting the position every 100ms or so